# Пересечение списков словарей по определенному значению ключа. Необходима оптимизация кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, списки, словари

Есть два списка словарей:

1. `types` - содержит информацию о названиях спортивных секциях и датах их посещения **одного** посетителя.
2. `user_list` - содержит информацию о людях которые тоже ходили в этот спортзал и даты их посещения.

   ```
   types = [{'type':'tango', 'date':'200118'}, 
   {'type':'box', 'date':'110217'},
   {'type':'strip', 'date':'170518'}]

   user_list = [{'name':'maxim', 'date':'200118'},
   {'name':'ivan', 'date':'110217'},
   {'name':'elena', 'date':'051018'},
   {'name':'gleb', 'date':'170518'},  
   {'name':'magas', 'date':'110217'},  
   {'name':'ivan', 'date':'170518'}, 
   {'name':'maxim', 'date':'110217'}]
   ```

### Задача

Необходимо из второго списка выбрать посетителей которые были в одни и те же даты с тем, кто указан в первом списке. И ещё условие: что были они в те же даты более одного раза.

### Результат

В итоге должен получится вот такой список:

```
[{'date': '110217', 'name': 'ivan'}, {'date': '170518', 'name': 'ivan'}, {'date': '200118', 'name': 'maxim'}, {'date': '110217', 'name': ‘maxim'}]
```

Если по другому объяснить, то нужно из второго списка выбрать строки значения полей ‘дата’, которые присутствуют в первом списке и встречаются во втором более одного раза. Ниже представлено мое решение, которое мне ужасно не нравится. Часть кода можно заменить на генераторы, но может быть кто нибудь знает более оптимальные инструменты?

```
types = [ {'type':'tango', 'date':'200118'},
{'type':'box', 'date':'110217'},
{'type':'strip', 'date':'170518'}]

user_list = [{'name':'maxim', 'date':'200118'},
{'name':'ivan', 'date':'110217'},
{'name':'elena', 'date':'051018'},
{'name':'gleb', 'date':'170518'},
{'name':'magas', 'date':'110217'},
{'name':'ivan', 'date':'170518'},
{'name':'maxim', 'date':'110217'}]

dates = [dct['date'] for dct in types]
names = list(set([dct['name'] for dct in user_list]))


goodusers = []
for name in names:
    res = []
    for u in user_list:
        if u['name']==name and u['date'] in dates:
            res.append(u)
    if len(res)>1:
        goodusers += res

print(goodusers)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы начали верно. Только нет смысла извлекать отдельно имена.

```
from itertools import groupby

dates = [dct['date'] for dct in types]
# фильтруем по совпадению дат
users = (d for d in user_list if d['date'] in dates)
# сортируем, для работы функции группировки
key_name = lambda u: u['name']
users = sorted(users, key=key_name)

double_users = []
for _, u in groupby(users, key=key_name):
    pool = tuple(u)
    if len(pool) > 1:
        double_users += pool
print(double_users)
```

Comment: Спасибо, еще как вариант я рассматривал решение через sqllite, но понимал что процесс импорта и экспорта из бд не быстрая штука.

Comment: sqllite может создавать БД в памяти. Так, к слову.

Comment: @AlexNasov. а вот запрос составить к `sqllite` к меня не получилось. Все равно вытаскивать в список и считать через `groupby`. Можете привести свой запрос?
а то `INNER JOIN`  я соединил базы, а отобрать "танцкющих более одного раза" через запрос не смог. Не знаю `SQL` ))
Тогда обавили бы сюда еще одно решение ))
Хотя оно громоздкое по записи.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Навскидку `SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE name in (SELECT u.name FROM types t LEFT JOIN user_list u ON t.date = u.date GROUP BY u.name HAVING count(u.name) > 1)`

Comment: @Vasyl Kolomiets в SQL есть такая же группировка (GROUP BY), далее по функции COUNT(имя)>1 получаем необходимые записи(см. комментарий выше). Но по скорости это будет не так эффективно, даже есть размещать БД в памяти.

Answer (score 6):

Такие задачи удобно решать используя модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd    # pip install pandas
```

сначала создадим DataFrame's из списков словарей:

```
u = pd.DataFrame(user_list)
t = pd.DataFrame(types)
```

получились след. DataFrame's:

```
In [59]: u
Out[59]:
     date   name
0  200118  maxim
1  110217   ivan
2  051018  elena
3  170518   gleb
4  110217  magas
5  170518   ivan
6  110217  maxim

In [60]: t
Out[60]:
     date   type
0  200118  tango
1  110217    box
2  170518  strip
```

теперь их можно отфильтровать одной коммандой:

```
res = u.merge(t[['date']]).sort_values('name').groupby('name').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

результат:

```
In [64]: res
Out[64]:
     date   name
1  110217   ivan
5  170518   ivan
0  200118  maxim
3  110217  maxim
```

тоже самое в виде списка словарей:

```
In [67]: res.to_dict('records')
Out[67]:
[{'date': '110217', 'name': 'ivan'},
 {'date': '170518', 'name': 'ivan'},
 {'date': '200118', 'name': 'maxim'},
 {'date': '110217', 'name': 'maxim'}]
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сравнить по скорости представленный вами вариант и Вариант выше.

Comment: @AlexNasov, на больших данных (10.000+ строки) Pandas обычно гораздо быстрее. На маленьких он может проигрывать.

Comment: @AlexNasov эффективность зависит не только от объема данных, но и от соотношения запись/чтение, и многого другого.

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю, у меня основной язык c++

Answer (score 2):

Ну тогда вот, благодаря автору вопроса и его [гостю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/306703/lecron):

```
import sqlite3 as li3
conn = li3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE visits (name TEXT, date TEXT)")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE types ( type TEXT, date TEXT)")

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO visits VALUES (?,?)", [list(d.values()) for d in user_list])
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO types VALUES (?,?)", [list(d.values()) for d in types])
conn.commit()

cursor.execute("""
               SELECT * FROM visits 
                        WHERE name IN
                        (SELECT visits.name FROM visits
                             INNER JOIN types ON visits.date=types.date
                             GROUP BY visits.name 
                             HAVING count(visits.name) >1)
               """)
print(cursor.fetchall())
cursor.close()
```

Выдает:

```
[('maxim', '200118'), ('ivan', '110217'), ('ivan', '170518'), ('maxim', '110217')]
```

Comment: я вот так изначально и хотел сделать, но все же мне кажется, что через встроенные библиотеки должно быть быстрее.

Comment: @AlexNasov - получается, что PANDAS это встроенный SQL.
А с другой стороны, если данные УЖЕ в файле, то пока прочтешь, пока засунешь в PANDAS...

Comment: Данные могут быть загружены из csv файлов, спарсены с веб-страниц и прочих источников.